# finding an exact string and save it and the following number in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file with lots of lines. Out of it I need to find 2 pattern of strings and save it to csv.

Example:

Text file contains:

```
NA:        2.0
slit uniformity at power:      3.6
integrated slit uniformity at power: 4.7
slit uniformity:     8.6
```

and the output in the csv I want

```
[NA] [2.0]
[slit uniformity] [8.6]
```

In short, I want to save an exact string in one column and the number next to it in the next column.

Comment: Have a look at the `re`-module, and play around with it's syntax. This is a classical problem for RegEx which is asked here really a lot and the man-page of pythons re is also a very good place to start this topic.

Answer (score 0):

If this data format happens to match a well-known format perfectly, you can parse it as that format.

In your sample data, the text field never includes any colons, or quotes, or backslash escapes, or anything "weird". Is that guaranteed to always be true?

If so, this is a valid CSV file, with colons for delimiters and optional whitespace heading the fields. So you can parse it that way. (Your *output* format is a little weird for CSV—normally you can't use separate "open" and "close" quoting character like that. But you're not asking about the output part here, so I'll cheat a bit.)

```
with open(inpath) as fin, open(outpath, 'w') as fout:
    w = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=' ')
    for text, number in csv.reader(fin, delimiter=':', skipinitialspace=True):
        w.writerow((f'[{text}]', f'[{number.strip()}]))
```

---

On the other hand, this may be simpler to do without thinking of either file as a weird CSV dialect and just parsing and generating the lines manually:

```
with open(inpath) as fin, open(outpath, 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        text, _, number = line.rstrip().partition(': ')
        fout.write(f'[{text}] [{number}]\n')
```

Of course the error handling won't be as nice if you have lines that break the format, since you're spreading the format specification implicitly over a few lines rather than defining it explicitly as a CSV dialect, but that may not be a problem.

Answer (score -2):

```
prefixes = ['NA:', 'slit uniformity:']

with open('file.txt') as input, open('file.csv', 'w') as output:
    for line in input:
        for prefix in prefixes:
            if line.startswith(prefix):
                output.write('[%s] [%s]\n' % (prefix[:-1], line[len(prefix)+1:-1]))
```

Comment: This doesn't give the output the OP wanted, it solves a different problem he didn't ask for, and it doesn't explain how to solve the problem he did ask for.

Comment: @abarnert I assumed that the `[]` in his sample output weren't literal, but were intended to represent column boundaries.  I have updated my answer.